# Trigger action when order is placed (woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to update product price [as shown on this example](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/rest-api-create-update-remove-products.html#update_product_price), and even when this works fine for me **I need this to happen when any new order gets completed**.

How can I trigger this to every order made? Is there any kind of event in Woocommerce for a new completed order, or similar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. This can be done with the `woocommerce_thankyou` action, as seen here:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_callback');

function my_callback( $order_get_id ) {

            $order = wc_get_order( $order_get_id ); // Do whatever you need with the order ID       
    }
}
```